# Why are the zeros necessary in this code? What purpose do they serve?

Tags: python

I am currently following along with an intro to Python course.
In the course we just wrote the following code.

```
def fizz_buzz(input):
    if (input % 3 == 0) and (input % 5 == 0):
        return "FizzBuzz"
    if input % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    if input % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    return input

print(fizz_buzz(7))
```

I understand what is happening in the program but I do not understand why it was necessary to set divisor == 0.

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn the difference between assignment (`=`) and testing for equality (`==`)

Comment: It's not the divisor that is zero, but you are comparing the _remainder_ of the division to zero. In other words, is `input` evenly divisible by 3 or 5. Also, it's a very bad idea to name a variable "input" because `input()` is a built-in function in Python and you are potentially making the input() function unusable in your script.

Comment: You are only shadowing the built-in function `input` inside `fizz_buzz`. If you have no intention of calling the built-in inside your function, there's no harm in using `input` as the parameter name.